# Quickblox - QBMessageListener never go into processMessage()

Tags: android, quickblox

I use Quickblox SDK in my Android app.

I can send messages in a QBPrivateChat and I can fetch them without problem.

I added a QBMessageListener to my QBPrivateChat in order to be notified as soon as a new message has been sent by the other user of the chat.

```
final QBMessageListener<QBPrivateChat> messageListener = new QBMessageListener<QBPrivateChat>() {

    @Override
    public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat privateChat, QBChatMessage chatMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "privateChatMessageListener - processMessage");
    }

    @Override
    public void processError(QBPrivateChat privateChat, QBChatException error, QBChatMessage originMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "privateChatMessageListener - processError");
    }

};

QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
privateChatManager.addPrivateChatManagerListener(new QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {

    @Override
    public void chatCreated(QBPrivateChat privateChat, boolean createdLocally) {
        Log.e(TAG, "QBPrivateChatManagerListener - chatCreated");

        if(!createdLocally)
            privateChat.addMessageListener(privateChatMessageListener);
    }

});

Integer opponentId = 1234;

QBPrivateChat privateChat = privateChatManager.getChat(opponentId);

if (privateChat == null)
    privateChat = privateChatManager.createChat(opponentId, messageListener);
else
    privateChat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
```

The problem is that the app never go through processMessage/processError. I try to figure it out for hours without success.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The right way here is to do

```
if (privateChat == null){
    privateChat = privateChatManager.createChat(opponentId, messageListener);
    privateChat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
}else{
}
```